# Own rolemanager provider without aspnetdb.mdf

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider, aspnetdb

I'm using rolemanager and security trimming for my menu. Since my server isnt too friendy about this ASPNETDB.mdf, I've created an own rolemanager in xml and c# class. But Visual studio is still creating my ASPNETDB file in APP_DATA. Now I've prevented this by commenting in machine.config file, but now i'm getting errors while debugging the project.

I think I have configured the rolemanager right, and looks like this:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyXmlProvider">
  <providers>
    <add type="Personal.Providers.MyXmlProvider" name="MyXmlProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Can someone see what is wrong? Is there something that could be useful to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a clear (**<clear />**) element at the beginning of your web.config settings. this will remove all other Providers (even the default)

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyXmlProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add type="Personal.Providers.MyXmlProvider" name="MyXmlProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```